# How do I change my username in the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: feature-request, support, android-app, display-names

I have the stack Exchange app on my phone, but I can't seem to find out how to change my username. It's the Stack Exchange Android app version 1.0.95.

Comment: In short: you can't. Must use a browser (there are browser apps for mobile devices too, e.g. Chrome or Firefox) , log in to the site in the browser, and change from there. SE is not mobile friendly.